# Laravel 8 Login credentials do not match

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get Laravel 8 running with an old database. Everything else is working except the login. Database is from Laravel 5.3 or 5.2 so quite old.

However, problem is that login doesn't seem to work at all, if I register and create a new account and try to log in, I'm getting:

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

Old accounts are not working either.

App Key exists. Session domain etc are correct.

I tried to recreate the auth logins. Made sure jetstream is there:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

ran:

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
```

also ran npm install and run dev afterwards.

Comment: How you check the credentials? like what is the method? are you use the Laravel auth or custom login?

Comment: Have you checked that the APP_KEYs match?  Or are you using 3rd api libraries?

Comment: @wiwekjannat it's default Laravel auth. And regarding the APP_KEY, how to check that the key's match? Not aware of that. Not using 3rd party libraries as far as I am aware.

Comment: First make sure you store your password in bcrypt form.

Comment: @wiwekjannat yup, absolutely did. Went through it all million times and saw nothing wrong, ended up doing it from the beginning with fresh installation and that did the trick. No idea what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this out.

Did a fresh install to sort it out. No idea about the cause.